# How to change the way the selection is handled in a WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

when I remove an item that is currently selected from the TreeView automatically the parent gets selected. I would like to change this behavior so the previous or the next child gets selected. I really don't know where to start ...

Any idea on how to accomplish this would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the SelectedItem by introducing a property such as IsSelected in your tree view node's datacontext class or model.

Assuming that you are binding a hierarchy of `TreeViewItemModel` class to the TreeView, you need to do the following

1. Add writeable `IsSelected` propertyb in `TreeViewItemModel`. Remember to raise property changed notification in the Setter of `IsSelected`.
2. Introduce this in the TreeView resources ...

   ```
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style>
   </TreeView.Resources>
   ```
3. After you delete a node, set the next or previous tree view child's `TreeViewItemModel` objects `IsSelected` as true.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Mmm, I'm not using a TreeViewItemModel ... I'm just binding the TreeView with a collection from the VM and using HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplates ... I really need to use the TreViewItemModel? Is this like a ViewModel for the TreeViewItem?

Comment: hey whatever view model is the data context of the tree view item, assume that is the TreeViewItemModel ... hence i said "ASSUMING" in my response. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Currently I have as datasource a collection that comes from the model. As I don't want to add such properties to model should I create a viewmodel to store it?

Answer (score 0):

TreeView has Items property, which is of type `ItemCollection`. [This type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611035.aspx) has some good events, like CollectionChanged or CurrentChanged. may be you should to spade this way?

Comment: Looks like a nice starting point. I'm on it. Thanks, I will upvote if I find something relevant.